# How to display one scrollable row in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, collectionview

I would like to show just one row in my collectionView. This one should be scrollable but the Simulator always includes a line break and my view is not scrollable at all.

This is my configuration in my storyboard:

[image: configuration]

But somehow this is the result:

[image: simulator]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make bigger UICollectionViewCells or reduce the UICollectionView height.
Probably in your datasource you have just 9 items and they all enter in the UICollectionView of that size.

Answer (score 0):

u can try

objective-c UICollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES

swift UICollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

this is independent from the count/size of your items